# Symfony 3, domain name shows Directory Structure

Tags: php, apache, symfony, configuration

I know this question is asked a lot but I read all the questions related to this but they didn't solve my problem.

I just deployed a Symfony 3 web app and I followed the [Symfony server configuration documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) just to find out that the www.domain.com displays the directory structure!

Here's the configuration that I used of file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.tld
ServerAlias www.domain.tld

DocumentRoot /var/www/project/web
<Directory /var/www/project/web>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>


ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
```

I can see the app when I go to www.domain.com/web and www.domain.com/web/app.php

I want to be able to visit www.domain.com and see the app.

Comment: which version of Apache are you running?

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: then please read as well the full doc you were poining to: a few things have changed since Apache 2.4 according to the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
AllowOverride None
```

to next one:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Remove section `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` And use standard Symfony's `.htaccess` file.

Also you need to set up PHP as module for your apache. Be sure to have uncommented line in `http.conf` that loads PHP module:

```
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

Comment: I tried all of these and it did not work. PHP is set up as a module for apache.

Comment: It says "You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information." which is good.  i don know what happened, i'm thinking of reinstalling apache

Comment: Ok. That's because you deployed it to remote server, that is not listed in trusted IPs in `app_dev.php`. So try to test `http://domain.tld/app.php`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your `DirectoryIndex app.php` or `DirectoryIndex dev_app.php` contained in your directory tag. This will cause apache to load app.php if a file has not been requested.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html

```
<Directory /var/www/project/web>
    DirectoryIndex app.php
    ...
</Directory>
```

Also make sure mod rewrite is enabled. 
`a2enmod rewrite`
You may have to use sudo.

One final note: 
        `Options -MultiViews` should be contained inside the `<Directory>` for use all the time and not just when `mod_rewrite` is enabled.